# SQL Server Configuration Manager not showing services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

My SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager is empty except for SQL Server Integration Services 12.0. It should show a bunch of other services, Like SQL Server, SQL Browser, SQL Agent, etc. I found a related question, and did the solution listed there. I successfully changed the value, but it didn't fix my issue. Here's the question/solution I tried:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5208/125955

I tried installing another instance of SQL Server but those services do not show up either. The Database Engine is for sure installed, I can connect to the server and do stuff via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Are you sure the Configuration Manager is the newest one on the system, and that the services you expect to show up aren't a higher version? Older config managers aren't going to show 2014+ services, and 2014 config manager won't show 2016+.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I do have an older Configuration Manager on this PC, but I am looking at the current one in this case.

Comment: if you are using "SQL Server 2014" then open the configuration manager from the command line: **sqlservermanager12.msc**.
_note: make sure to run this as administrator_

Comment: @HamzaRabah Looks the same. Configuration Manager, and only shows Integration Services...

Comment: What do you see in Services?

Answer (score 4):

Start-->Run and type services.msc and check installed SQL Services.  Do you see the installed SQL Server services?
Please refer below articles.

These may help:

- [SQL Server configuration manager is empty](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2c4ca10-07cc-432c-8f84-1ac1733f8ae3/sql-server-configuration-manager-is-empty?forum=sqlgetstarted)
- [Why is SQL Server Configuration Manager Missing Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2492/why-is-sql-server-configuration-manager-missing-services/)

Answer (score 2):

you could be looking at the wrong version of SQL configuration manager , if multiple versions are installed on your server.

Comment: Yes, In my case, it was due to the fact I was opening wrong Configuration Manager. I upgraded from 2019 to 2022 version but I was still clicking "SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager", while I should click "SQL Server 2022 Configuration Manager" that was listed after.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the SQL Server installation is complete. The management studio might be installed, but there is no SQL server instance.